# Drawing a path with multiple vertices on a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a task of drawing a path on a panel using mouse click. The path should be some thing like left 
click and release at (x1, y1), move the mouse and then left click and release at (x2, y2). Then a line should be drawn from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2). Now this time when I move my mouse to other location say (x3,y3) and then left click & release, a line should be drawn from  (x2, y2) to (x3,y3).

In this manner I want to draw a path with multiple vertices say up to (Xn, Yn).

Currently I could able to draw only from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2).

`using (Pen draw_pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, PEN_WIDTH))
   {
   g.DrawLine(draw_pen, _StartPt.X, _StartPt.Y, _EndPt.X, _EndPt.Y);
   }`

Does anyone can let me know whether this is achievable ? If yes can you please provide sample code snippet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list or a collectible of your choice, then whenever a click/letgo happens add the current point to your list, after adding draw over your complete list, always from one element to the next until the end.

Comment: Or simply draw on an `Image` instead then draw this `Image` on the `Panel`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GraphicsPath to represent it.  Here's a simple example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private int PEN_WIDTH = 5;
    private Point lastPoint = new Point(-1, -1);
    private System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath GP = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
        this.MouseDown += Form1_MouseDown;
    }

    void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        if (lastPoint.X == -1 && lastPoint.Y == -1)
        {
            lastPoint = pt;
        }
        else
        {
            GP.AddLine(lastPoint, pt);
            this.Refresh();
        }
        lastPoint = pt;
    }

    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen draw_pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, PEN_WIDTH)) 
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.DrawPath(draw_pen, GP);
        }
    }

}
```

Obviously you could track the number of clicks if you wanted to stop after a certain number of vertices.  You could use a `List<GraphicsPath>` to represent more than one set of lines.

Comment: Thanks so much.I will give it a try and let you know.